# combobox items connect to column table in C# winforms

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms, sql-server-2008

i have a form:"Emloyees" with a combobox1. 
i have a table "City".
when I add an emloyee to the my "Emloyees" **table** I open the comboBox1 all the cities i have and i choose one.
if in the table City I add a city, I want that when i try to add an emloyee when I open the comboBox1 there will be the city i just add. i want a connection between the table City and the comboBox1 in the form

Comment: You need to be a lot more clear what you are trying to do and provide code to show what you have tried so far.

Comment: i dont have anything...just a form with comboBox1 and a table:"Emloyees" thats it...i just need the data in the table will transfer to the items collection in the comboBox1

Comment: Okay, then you need to be more clear. What is in the table? Is it a textbox? Will things be added at runtime? Or do you mean whatever you add before you 'press play' will be populated in the combobox at runtime? Please provide as much detail as you can, maybe some screenshots will help.

Comment: ok...i will edit my question and add more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make an sql query that get the Employee and then you can display it in the combobox

i have similar project so i know

its something like that

```
  CityComboBoxEmp.DataSource = CityShow.UseSqlCommand("Select * From City").Tables[0];
```

CityShow is use class that's runing sql commands